# Connection to a spring boot micro-service from a monolithic spring app

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, microservices, spring-cloud

So we have a Spring app which runs on localhost:8080

As part of a requirement we need this application to connect to a micro service. The micro service has 2 components.
One running on localhost:8888 - X
Another on localhost:7777 - Y

We have the spring discovery server running on localhost:8761

How can we connect to the micro service X or Y from the monolithic spring application through the discovery server.

We can directly connect to localhost:8888 or localhost:7777

But is there a way to do it through the discover server

Comment: Sure do you already have a discovery service and where are your microservices running?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli for now discovery server is running in localhost:8761. For now everything is in local but in different different ports.

Comment: Eureka is not a proxy

Comment: You can use Eureka Discovery client for that purpose like below:
    `Application application 
      = eurekaClient.getApplication("micro-service-X-name");
    InstanceInfo instanceInfo = application.getInstances().get(0);
    String hostname = instanceInfo.getHostName();
    int port = instanceInfo.getPort();`
 For more details please go through: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-netflix-eureka

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 ways to do the call from the monolithic app to a microservice registered in the discovery-service:

1. After adding and enabling discovery service dependencies you can
   inject `eurekaClient` bean and get an application url
   ("round-robinned" or not).
2. Use the @LoadBalanced restTemplate and send requests to
   "http://service-name/url" where ribbon will change "service-name" to
   a valid URL automatically
3. And finally the best option is to rely on [feign](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-feign.html) client. It uses
   discovery service implicitly.